# How to set the description to a given patchset in gerrit

Tags: rest, authentication, curl, gerrit, field-description

I want to set the description to a given patchset in Gerrit with the official REST API.

When I execute the command following, Gerrit Authentication is required.

My curl is this:

```
curl -u userName:password -X PUT 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-d '{"description": "test message"}' 
 http://gerritServer:port/changes/project~master~changeId/revisions/revisionId/description
```

I have added the Gerrit authentication, why do I still need authentication?

Comment: IO tried to edit your post but I have no idea what this means:  `When I execute the command following the next,`  Where is the 'next'?

Comment: Could you post the exact error message?